# Session Variable Causes Controller Actions to Fire One at a Time

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that is executing actions one at a time, almost like it puts my requests in a queue and then responds to each in turn. So, for example, if I click 2 or 3 buttons that are set up to POST to my controller, the controller will *eventually* fire all the actions, but not right when I click the button.

After tearing my project apart I realized this strange behaviour is somehow caused by setting a Session variable in my default controller action..

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index() //Start Page
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SomeString"] = "SomeValue";
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public void Run(string json)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The index view just contains two elements:

```
    <a href="#" class="submit">Run</a>
    <a href="Home/OtherPage">Other Page</a>
```

And AJAX for the button click:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".submit").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Run',
            data: "SomeString",
            dataType: "text"
        }); 
    }
}
```

When I remove the line of code setting my session variable, I can click the run button (which starts the long-running loop), click my "OtherPage" button, and instantly navigate to the "OtherPage" view. If I *do* set the session variable, run the loop, and then click the "OtherPage" button, my app hangs until the loops finish and then navigates to the "OtherPage" view.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: fire and forget is a bad design for web server. Try to avoid it whenever possible

Comment: @Steve Do you mind explaining why? I don't have to guarantee the task completes succesfully. I am expecting it to fail occasionally and have logging and error-handling built out for those scenarios. I am just wondering why I'm glued to a single thread while I use "Async" technologies?

Comment: This is not fire and forget since you're awaiting the call. `Task.Run(() => yourMethodCall)` would be fire and forget.

Comment: how did you determine that all other actions wait for the previous one to finish before starting? I would be very surprised if that's the case

Comment: I put a breakpoint on a different controller action, started the "Run()" method, and then clicked a button for the different controller action (which returns a new View). The app waits until Run completely finishes and then calls the action of my controller and returns the view.

Comment: default thread pool size is 100. Meaning that it could handle 100 concurrent requests without blocking each other. Unless you have some lock in your base controller or some sort this shouldn't happen.

Comment: @Steve It seems you are correct. I created a blank MVC application, copy/pasted this code, and was able to call as many other controller actions as I wanted while my loop ran in the background. I am trying to figure out what could prevent that same behavior in the other app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer for your question is:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(()=>{//your code})
```

The long and less dangerous answer is: use some queue system, like RabbitMQ or AWS SQS or MSMQ or whatever. Background tasks on web apps is not the best thing you can do in your life, even if the response (success or failure) is not important for you.

**EDIT**:

If you are using Session State, you probably would need to disable the session state - or set it readonly - in the controller you want some parallelism. Add the following attribute at the controller you want it:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
public class FooController...
```

This page explains why this can be necessary in some cases:
http://hogaf.github.io/archive/2014/11/13/why-asp.net-requests-are-processed-sequentially

But, again, this is a very bad practice. You had to deal with with `ThreadAbortException`s and will be subject to a lot of other problems.

Comment: Consider this ,imitation before using https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-background-processes-in-asp-net/                         
 The AppDomain shutdown can only be delayed 90 seconds (It’s actually the minimum of HttpRuntimeSection.ShutdownTimeout and processModel shutdownTimeLimit). If you have so many items queued that they can’t be completed in 90 seconds, the ASP.NET runtime will unload the AppDomain without waiting for the work items to finish.

Comment: I just made a significant edit to the question since I've identified why concurrent requests were not working

Comment: @BrandonChurch you had to set the SessionStateAttribute in the controller you want to fire and forget. I edited the answer with that information. But, keep in mind you should not do that kind of solution on production code.

Comment: @AdilsondeAlmeidaJr Awesome thanks! Is the reasoning behind this to prevent dirty reads of session data? This was just a quick way for me to distinguish my users, but I think I should be using my OwinContext instead.

Comment: I think it´s more about the way SessionState works, I looked at the code of the providers. By the way, a stateless application would be a better choice nowadays.